# PHP - fopen не открывает адрес с крякозяброй в строке

Tags: php, fopen

Всем привет. 
Есть страница с адресом содержащим "/Al_Kharāj/"
символ "ā" всему виной

fopen в PHP не хочет открывать такой адрес, говорит error, хотя в адресной строке браузера все открывается.

Подскажите, есть выход из этой ситуации?

```
  $url='https://www.yr.no/place/Jordan/Irbid/Al_Kharāj/forecast.xml';
//  $url=rawurlencode($url);
  $fd=fopen($url,"r");
  if (!fd)  echo 'Error';
```

PHP Version 5.3.3

Comment: Наверняка есть. Добавьте код, как открываете. Какая версия PHP?

Comment: добавил в первое сообщение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlencode` не работает, потому что экранизирует весь URL, включая `/` и `:`. Нужно кодировать выборочно

```
$url='https://www.yr.no/place/Jordan/Irbid/Al_Kharāj/forecast.xml';
$url = explode("/", $url);
for ($i = 3; $i < count($url); $i++) {
    $url[$i] = urlencode($url[$i]);
}
$url = implode("/", $url);
$fd=fopen($url,"r");
if (!fd)  echo 'Error';
```

Comment: не проще уже сразу сделать как сделал @Farkhod Daniyarov ? Зачем ради одного действия, городить велик?)

Comment: @And Предполагаю, что в примере частный случай, и на практике понадобится так обрабатывать не один URL

Comment: Странный вы. Если не один урл, тогда проще будет уже регулярку юзать, быстрее будет. Да и, вопрос за конкретный случай.

Comment: @And Ну так чтож не предложили свой вариант?

Comment: Вы читаете комменты или пропускаете мимо? @FarkhodDaniyarov дал ответ, он меня опередил, я не стал писать - ко всему `rawurlencode` будет работать медленее `urlencode`.

Comment: @And когда начал писать ответ, ответа @FarkhodDaniyarov еще небыло. Ну а с `rawurlencode` каюсь, просто скопипастил из вопроса) На идеальное решение не претендовал, просто наглядно показал в чем именно была проблема

Comment: Nikita да слушайте вы его больше. Всё правильно вы написали вначале. rawurlencode - для кодировки пути, urlencode - для кодировки query запроса в url. И о какой скорости тут идёт речь? Человек не парсит миллионные базы урлов, ему надо разобрать всего одну ссылку

Comment: Понял! Кстати, если использовать `foreach` и `join`, код станет еще быстрее. Плюсану+ Но для более гибкой ситуации, можно будет воспользоваться регулярными выражениями и за место циклов и преобразований, сделать разбор в регулярке, но я не стану писать ее, так как автору нужен статичный вариант, который дал @FarkhodDaniyarov.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте функцию [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)

```
<?php
if (!fopen('https://www.yr.no/place/Jordan/Irbid/' . urlencode('Al_Kharāj') . '/forecast.xml','r')) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    echo 'Success!';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Функция:

```
<?php
function mb_rawurlencode($url){
$encoded='';
$length=mb_strlen($url);
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
$encoded.='%'.wordwrap(bin2hex(mb_substr($url,$i,1)),2,'%',true);
}
return $encoded;
}
?>
```

Пример:

```
<?php
echo 'http://site.com/',
    mb_rawurlencode('Al_Kharāj');
?>
```

Comment: Велосипед конкретный, для этого уже есть готовые функции, сразу из коробки...

Comment: Тогда ждём вашего ответа из коробки работающего на старых версиях

Comment: `urlencode` Вам для чего? А теперь внимание!!! `urlencode` был с 4 версии, а взять к примеру `wordwrap` который был не ранее `4.0.2`, а `mb_*` еще позднее. Ко всему, самый достаточный ответ дал @FarkhodDaniyarov.

Comment: urlencode тут не нужен, его используют для кодирования query строки. Для кодирования пути нужен rawurlencode

Comment: Нет! Его используют для формирования `unicode` в ссылке, чтобы задать `HTTP` вопрос серверу.

Comment: Напишите наконец свое решение "супербыстрое"

Comment: Самое быстрое решение у @FarkhodDaniyarov.